# The limit of the integral when the set is decreasing in probability to zero.

Tags: integration, probability-theory, expectation

This is an exercise problem(#2 in section 3.2) from 'A course in probability theory'.

If $E(\vert X \vert ) < \infty$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} P(A_n) = 0,$ then $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{A_n} X \ dP = 0.$

I tried using the modulus inequality of integrals but I cannot get the result. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer given by @d.k.o. is almost correct: Let us assume that $\int_{A_n} X \, dP \not \to 0$. Then there is some $\epsilon > 0$ and a subsequence $A_{n_k}$ with $|\int_{A_{n_k}} X \, dP | \geq \epsilon$ for all $k$.

Now, since $P(A_n) \to 0$, we can choose a further subsequence $A_{n_{k_\ell}}$ (which we call $B_\ell$ for brevity) with $P(B_\ell) \leq 2^{-\ell}$. In particular, $\sum_\ell P(B_\ell) <\infty$, so that the Borel Cantelli lemma implies $P(B_\ell \text{ i.o.}) = 0$ ($B_\ell$ infinitely often). This means $\chi_{B_\ell} \to 0$ almost surely.

Now we can use the dominated convergence theorem to conclude

$$
\int_{B_\ell} X \, dP \to 0,
$$

which is in contradiction to $|\int_{A_{n_k}} X \, dP|\geq \epsilon$ for all $k$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand now!

Answer (score 1):

The function $$\mu (A) =\int_A |X(\omega ) | dP(\omega ) $$ is a finite measure since $$E (|X|) <\infty .$$
Since $P(A) =0$ implies that $\mu (A) =0$ the measure $\mu $ is absolutely continuous with respect to the measure $P.$ Hence the condition $P(A_n ) \to 0 $ implies $\mu (A_n ) \to 0 $  and therefore if $P(A_n ) \to 0 $ we have $$\left |\int_{A_n} X(\omega )dP(\omega )\right|\leqslant \int_{A_n } |X(\omega )| dP(\omega ) =\mu (A_n ) \to 0.$$

Comment: It is true that $P(A_n) \to 0$ implies $\mu(A_n) \to 0$, but why exactly? For example if $\mu$ is an **infinite** measure, this does not hold in general.

Comment: but $\mu$ is finite.

Comment: Yes, what I am saying is that you should provide the argument, since it is nontrivial (and essentially equivalent to what the OP wants to show).

Comment: Thank you. I understand the proof but as @PhoemueX mentioned, it would have been better if you gave a proof of the limit argument.

Answer (score 0):

Since $X1_{A_n}\xrightarrow{p}0$ and $|X1_{A_n}|\le |X|$ with $\mathbb{E}|X|<\infty$ the dominated convergence theorem (for sequences converging in prob.) implies that $\mathbb{E}X1_{A_n}\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: It is not true in general that $1_{A_n} \to 0$ almost surely. Consider for example the sequence of sets $[0,1], [0,1/2], [1/2, 1], [0,1/3], [1/3, 2/3], [2/3, 1], \dots$.

Comment: But $\mathbb{E}[\lim1_{A_n}]=0$ ...

Comment: No, with my example above, for **evey** $x \in [0,1]$ there are infinitely many $n$ with $1_{A_n} = 1$.

Comment: Assuming the limit $\lim 1_{A_n}$ exists (almost everywhere), which is not the case in general, in particular not for the example given above.